# Dictionary issue

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary defined as Dictionary  (string, object).  I'm accessing other values (strings) in the dictionary without issue, but when I try to access an 'int' I'm getting an issue. When I try and compile this:

```
            int score = obj["score"] as int;
```

I get the error: 'The 'as' operator cannot be used with a non-nullable value type 'int'

More than happy to stick my head int the sand, I recoded it to this:

```
        int score = (int) obj["score"];
```

...it does compile but at run time I receive this error:

InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What type did you put into the dictionary ? Almost certainly not an int. I think the InvalidCastException message will tell you the exact types, try pasting the message into your question.

Comment: Did you inspect what type the object is at "score"?

Comment: Don't forget that when you unbox, you need to unbox it to the same type that was boxed *before* converting it to an int (assuming it wasn't an int in the first place, which it doesn't look to be). It seems that either it's not an int at all or it's something that could be converted to an int but was initially stored as another type (e.g. double). Can you confirm the type stored?

Comment: small example of complete case would be appreciated

Comment: Your small scenario works for me. I would suggest you verify the object at location "score" actually contains something that can be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.90).aspx

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception

Int32 is not a nullable type, so `as` cannot be applied to it.

```
int score = obj["score"] as int? ?? 0;
```

This would work, notice it is casting to `Nullable<int>` and then coalesing to 0 if the cast fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value is a string:

```
int score = -1;
int.TryParse(obj["score"], out score);
```

You must [parse the integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) from the string.

Comment: That's assuming there is a string in the dictionary for the key `score`.

Comment: @driis He said he is getting other strings just fine, so I assumed. You're right, and he could be doing a 'value.ToString()' to get those strings.  Assumption is now noted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just simply use Convert.ToInt32(value), Int32.Parse(), or Int32.TryParse [as bland suggested]. All of those should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way :

```
 int score = Convert.ToInt32(obj["score"]);
```